# Cannot Execute File in Terminal OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, executable

I can run compile in OSX terminal using `g++ -Wall -c pa1.cpp -o pa1`. Which creates `pa1`, so I know my compilation works in terminal but I am having issues with execution. I have tried `./pa1` , `./a.out`, `pa1` and few others. I believe the issue is with Xcode, yet the fact that my code will compile in terminal and creates an executable makes me unsure. Thought, I would ask here for suggestions before reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: The `-c` option prevents the linker from being run, so the output file will be an object file, not an executable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `g++ pa1.cpp -o pa1` and then you'll be able to run your new executable as `./pa1`. This require that your whole program is in `pa1.cpp`. If it is spread in multiple files, you'll have to list all of them on the command-line.

As said in the comments, the `-c` option means compile, ie. Create an object file that can be passed to the linker to build an executable. If you don't use this option, `g++` will first compile any source file, then invoke the linker on all the object files to create an executable named `a.out` by default (name comes from historical reason).

You can see that the output of your command was not an executable binary but an intermediate object file by using the `file` util.

Comment: I completely forgot " If it is spread in multiple files, you'll have to list all of them on the command-line." Thank you very much!